Is 7-zip usable in a closed device?
I want to use 7zzs in a closed linux device to zip some files (I don't modify any source code of 7-zip, just use it). I found that 7-zip is using LGPL license, and I know that LGPL v3 prohibits users from using in closed devices. However, I found that in 7-zip license page it said
you can redistribute it and/or
    modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
    License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
    version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

And I found in this answer that it seems that I don't need to make sure users must be able to modify LGPL v2.1 parts in a closed device.
So, what I would like to make sure is that is 7-zip LGPL v2.1 or v3? Can I use 7-zip in a closed device as along as I declare in document that I'm using 7-zip and offer the way to get the source code of 7-zip?

You can redistribute 7-Zip and/or modify it under the terms of either LGPL-2.1 or any later version, including LGPL-3.0.
If you are redistributing the said closed devices, simply declaring in document that you're using 7-Zip and offering the way to get the source code of 7-Zip is not going to be enough on LGPL-2.1 nor on LGPL-3.0.
You need to provide the means for the users of your closed devices to replace the LGPL-2.1-or-later licensed 7-Zip code on the system with their own. You also need to comply with the other requirements of LPGL-2.1-or-later.

For LGPL v2.1, you don't actually need to provide the means to replace the LGPL code; however the program linked with the library must work if the user provides one (Section 6(b)). Making it very hard to provide the library is exactly what Tivo did...

Thank you for your kind reply! Then I'd like to know, I hava a large project, and only a very little part uses 7-zip. Can I just offer this little part software to the user but keep the large project in the closed device and don't offer it to the user? Is this legal?

For example, I wrote a web server, and user can do a lot of operations in the closed device via http. One operation is to compress files, and I use 7-zip to do this. Can I just pacakge a minimal web server that can do compressing by 7z-ip and offer it to the user?

Also other programs in the close device may call the compress operation via the web server

I agree with @PhilipKendall.  This is from LGPL-2.1 and the LGPL-3.0 section 4(d) is very similar. There are lots of moving parts in your three comments, OP. If you can present your questions in a more coherent way and if your questions are of clarifying type (as oppposed to a completely different question) then I would be happy to provide clarification.

@ChuangMen For a web server application, you're only obligated to honour the (L)GPL requirements towards people who actually obtain a copy of the software. Because of the way the Web works, this does not include visitors that use a Web browser to visit your page. If I Press Ctrl+U View Source or use Developer Tools on your page, the server software is nowhere to be found among the code that is sent to my browser.

Thank you all! I have decided to implement this function by writing my own code using python's standard library zipfile.
